# Pass parameter to COM object function in PHP

Tags: php, com

I have COM object, that contains function:

```
[id(1)]  HRESULT tst1([out] LONG * l, [out, retval] LONG * e );
```

Create this object and use in PHP:

```
$f = new COM('App.MyObj');
$f->tst1($i);
```

Got error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message  
( ! ) com_exception: Parameter 0: Type mismatch.
```

How I should pass parameter in my case?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you don't need to pass any parameter to method `tst1()`, since it only uses `out` parameters.
So you must catch the result of that method inside an object variable and then access the properties of that object:

```
$f = new COM('App.MyObj');
$result = $f->tst1();
print_r($result); // find out the $result object structure
```